# Slick edge event not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have this is script;

```
var $carousel = $("[data-carousel]");

$carousel.on('edge', function(event, slick, direction){
  console.log("edge");
});

$carousel.slick({
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  accessibility: false,
  draggable: false,
  infinite: false,
  prevArrow: $("[data-carousel-prev]"),
  nextArrow: $("[data-carousel-next]"),
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1370,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

But when reaching the edge, it does not trigger any edge event
following the docs seems ok
I'm using slick 1.5.6

Comment: Same here. Can you find the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `edge` event only fires when overscrolling happens.

Such overscrolling can only happen if draggable is set to true and you drag over the last slide.

Using the buttons **will not trigger** the `edge` event.

If you are looking to execute some code if the "next" button is triggered at the last slide, use the indexes in combination with the `afterChange` event.

Disclaimer: used version in this answer: 1.5.9